# Need to build MySQL replication with TSL cert between onPremises server as Master and Azure flex server as Slave

Tags: mysql-5.7, azure, master-slave-replication, ssl

I have a requirement

Need to build MySQL replication with TSL cert between onPremises server as Master and Azure flex server as Slave .

On Master & slave host ssl is enabled . also i have followed blog https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/how-to-data-in-replication#link-source-and-replica-servers-to-start-data-in-replication
But still Master_SSL_Allowed = No showing . Kindly share some valuable inputs .